# What is the difference between DI principle and "Program to interface, not to implementation"?

Tags: oop, inversion-of-control

I don't understand the differences between the Dependency Inversion and the famous phrase which is presented in the Gof book, "Program to interface, not to implementation". 
The definition of DIP states these principles:

1. High-level modules should not depend on low-level modules. Both should depend on abstractions.
2. Abstractions should not depend upon details. Details should depend upon abstractions.

It seems that both principles do the the same thing: decouple the interface from the implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Program to interface, not to implementation" is a good advise in the general sense in OOP (even if your language doesn't support the concept of an interface). The idea is that the object sending the message should not care about the specifics of the receiver (e.g. which class is instance of or if it belongs to a given hierarchy), as long as it can answer a set of messages (and thus carry out a set of behaviors). If you look at the patterns in GoF, one of the main bottom lines is that, as long as you program against an interface, you can replace the target object with another without having to change anything in the client.

Regarding the [Dependency Inversion Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) I see it just as a concrete application of the former idea. You are applying the idea of programming to an interface instead of a concrete class in the context of a layered architecture, with the aim of decoupling the lower layers from the upper ones in order to obtain flexibility and reusability.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a `Computer` `class` defined as below:

```
public class Computer
{
    public string OwnerName{get; set;}

    public int RAMCapacity{get; set;} //Hardware based property

    public string OperatingSystem{get; set;} //Software based property
}
```

Now, programming to `Interface` says that as per above code comments you should create an `ISoftwareComponents` and `IHardwareComponents` interface and move those properties to respective interfaces and implement both interfaces in `Computer` class as below:

```
public interface ISoftwareComponents
{
    string OperatingSystem{get; set;}
}

public interface IHardwareComponents
{
    int RAMCapacity{get; set;}
}


public class Computer : ISoftwareComponent, IHardwareComponents
{
    public string OwnerName{get; set;}

    public int RAMCapacity{get; set;} //IHardwareComponents property

    public string OperatingSystem{get; set;} //ISoftwareComponents property
}
```

now the client code for the `Computer` class can use code like this:

```
Computer comp = new Computer();

//software requirements can use the below code:
string os = ((ISoftwareComponents)comp).OperatingSystem; // and, other variations by method calls

//hardware requirements can use the below code
int memory = ((IHardwareComponents)comp).RAMCapacity; //and, other variations
```

You could also pass only the Software and Hardware interface parts of the computer to other classes and methods as below:

```
public void SetHardware(IHardwareComponents comp)
{
    comp.RAMCapacity = 512;
}
```

Explore more on above examples and you would know more.